# Update document in array MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know this question has been asked in various ways before but I've read them all and I can't get it to work with the below:

Here is a doc example:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("583659c5be5f0e6f70c95633"),
"firstName" : "da",
"lastName" : "ksk",
"email" : "papap@aol.com",
"surveyResults" : [
    {
        "mouseTracking" : [ ],
        "result" : "White",
        "question" : "What color website do you prefer?",
        "questionNumber" : "0"
    },
    {
        "mouseTracking" : [ ],
        "result" : "Laptop",
        "question" : "What device do you use most to browse the web?",
        "questionNumber" : "1"
    }]
```

Here is what I am trying to run in mongoose and having no luck:

```
db.results.update({_id:userIdVar, surveyResults: {$elemMatch: {questionNumber: questionNumVar}}},{$set:{"surveyResults.$.result" : newResultVar}});
```

I have variables being used and I know they have the proper values to match what is in the places I need to update. Is there something I am missing??

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Answer (score 0):

As far I guess type miss match to element match. In your data example **questionNumber** is string so if you compare with integer type **questionNumVar** then it should not work. so to compare need to convert to string (if integer) otherwise should be working.

can try like:

```
db.results.update({_id:userIdVar, surveyResults: {$elemMatch: {questionNumber: questionNumVar.toString()}}},{$set:{"surveyResults.$.result" : newResultVar}}).exec();
```

then it should be working.

Comment: I have a funny thing that I completely didn't realize I missed. I wasn't actually running the command. I added mongoose debug along with console logging everywhere and saw the console log being fired without the  mongoose debug fired on the running of update.  Added .exec and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I added a few levels of console logging throughout the conditionals and before and after the update and saw that all of the paths were being traveled. Then I added the line:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

This logs all mongoose interactions with the db. I saw that my command I pasted wasn't even running! Turns out I accidentally left off the

```
 .exec()
```

at the end so it wasn't executing the command. After a hours of checking and triple checking my syntax, variable types, it was just this.

I did in the process of this learn more about the $ operator and you should read up on it if you don't know it's place in mongoose/mongodb